# Соединить два элемента списка в один

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, list, кортежи

Есть два списка:

```
list_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list_2 = ['1', '2', '3']
```

Необходимо получить список:

```
list_3 = ['a-1', 'b-2', 'c-3']
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Функция [**zip()**](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp)
берёт на вход несколько списков и создаёт из них список кортежей.

```
list_3 = [ f'{i}-{j}' for i, j in zip(list_1, list_2) ]
```

Answer (score 8):

в довесок к ответу @S. Nick:

или так

```
list_3 = [*map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}-{x[1]}', zip(list_1, list_2))]
```

или так

```
list_3 = [*map(lambda x: '-'.join(x), zip(list_1, list_2))]
```

или так

```
list_3 = [*map(lambda x, y: f'{x}-{y}', list_1, list_2)]
```

или так (спасибо @Михаил Муругов):

```
list_3 = [*map('{}-{}'.format, list_1, list_2)]
```

или так (пока что самая короткая запись)

```
list_3 = [*map('-'.join, zip(list_1, list_2))]
```

Comment: Вместо лямбд можно использовать `'{}-{}'.format`.